# Specifying Google service account in gsutil for GCP operations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil

It seems Google Cloud SDK requires the service account to be activated via `gcloud auth ...`. Without it, `gsutil cp` or `gsutil rsync` would not work. This does not work very well in the continuous integration environments or other cron-based, when one may have multiple jobs running at the same time, thus creating a potential conflict when different scripts try to use different accounts in parallel.

Is it possible to pass the google service account as a parameter to `gsutil`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid race conditions when running gsutil commands, I'd recommend to create separate installations and run each one with its absolute path. You can then configure each installation with its own credentials with the `gsutil config` command (see documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config)).

Note that by default the configuration file is written to ~/.boto and a new configuration would replace the previous one. You can however specify a different destination file with the `-o` option.

Comment: This answer is close, but not *quite* accurate. Separate gsutil installations will all write to the same state directory by default (`$HOME/.gsutil`), as well as loading the same default boto config files. To avoid race conditions, you can (and should) use the same gsutil installation, but specify a different `state_dir` and/or boto config file for invocations that might overlap. This can be set either at the boto config file level, or with the `-o` option, e.g. `gsutil -o "GSUtil:state_dir=$HOME/.gsutil2" cp src dst`.

Comment: It's also worth noting, if you're using an installation of gsutil bundled with gcloud, that gcloud will pass its currently active credentials to gsutil.  If you want to avoid this and use multiple different credentials/accounts for overlapping invocations, you should manage credentials via gsutil directly (using separate boto config files), not gcloud.  You can disable gcloud's auto-credential-passing behavior via running `gcloud config set pass_credentials_to_gsutil false`.